# Перевернуть строку и заменить символы

Tags: sqlite

В таблице даты записаны как "2020-01-01".
Как составить запрос так, чтобы поменять все в столбце на "01.01.2020"?

Comment: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-substr/

Comment: скомбинировать с https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-string-functions/sqlite-concat/